# Error when get the Z value to point from the attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, z-value

I have imported point from a csv file with the xyz coordinates in the attribute like this in QGIS.

[image]

And now I want to add Z value to the point. I try to use v.to.3d to add Z value but I get the error. How to fix this or Is there any tool to do like this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Thank you for taking the [tour]. Please [edit] your question to include the text of any errors as opposed to (or in addition to) using screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the "Set Z Value" tool instead -- it can be used to set geometry's z value as either a fixed value or from either a feature attribute or expression based value.